# Using the phrase 'by the time' with the intention to show my aim

Tags: phrase-usage

everyone. I was wondering whether the following usage of the phrase 'by the time' sounds natural.

> By the time I complete my internship, I aim to develop great products.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some perspectives on improving the sentence.

When reading it there appears to be nothing wrong with the 'by the time' part, it's the 'aim to develop' which doesn't seem exactly correct.

I would expect to read:

> "By the time I complete my internship, I will have achieved X Y and Z."

or

> "By the time I complete my internship, I hope to have become an expert in this or that"

or

> "By the time I complete my internship, I believe I will have a vision for the next step in the development of the product line."

In all the examples, 'by the time' you have done A, you will have accomplished B, whatever that is.

However, you are saying after you have done A, you will "aim" to do something.  "Aim" means "try" and it doesn't sound like an accomplishment.

An alternative to 'by the time' is 'after'.

> After I complete my internship, I aim to continue on and develop truly great products.

So, keeping the original sentence with the fewest modifications possible, 'after' could be a better choice than 'by the time'.